# Rails - in Rails Console, when you save and get false, How can you find out why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails Console, I'm creating a record and then entering @record.save and I get false but I can't figure out why? Is there a way in Rails C to output why the save failed?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The errors are accessed through the `errors` instance method. Example:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 > c = Company.new
=> #<Company id: nil, name: nil, link: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :002 > c.save
=> false 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :003 > c.errors
=> #<OrderedHash {:name=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Answer (score 9):

If it is false then there are errors

In the console type

```
@record.errors
```

Comment: not always. I'm trying to figure out why a single perfectly valid record won't save